# strcpy works fine, even though memory is not allocated

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, strcpy

Below c++ program works fine, even though i have not allocated any memory to `chr`.
I went through google, SO and came across this 
[Why does this intentionally incorrect use of strcpy not fail horribly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139867/why-does-this-intentionally-incorrect-use-of-strcpy-not-fail-horribly)

Here the program works fine for destination which has space less than the source.
Does that apply in my case also,`strcpy` writes into a random location in the heap?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Mystring
{
    char *chr;
    int a;
    public:
    Mystring(){}
    Mystring(char *str,int i);
    void Display();

};

Mystring::Mystring(char *str, int i)
{
   strcpy(chr,str);
   a = i;
}

void Mystring::Display()
{
    cout<<chr<<endl;
    cout<<a<<endl;
}


int main()
{
    Mystring a("Hello world",10);
    a.Display();
    return 0;
}
output:-
Hello world
10
```

I tried the same thing with another c++ program, with any class and class member, and i was able to see the crash.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *src = "Hello world";
    char *dst;
    strcpy(dst,src);
    cout<<dst<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me understand the behavior in the first c++ program.Is memory allocated somehow or `strcpy` is writing to some random memory location.

Comment: It's simply undefined behavior, nothing will be allocated automatically.

Comment: It´s **not** fine, you´re just not seeing the problem. Yet. And that´s the most "horrible fail" because you might not realize such a bug until something really bad happened (not in this toy program, but in realworld use...losing all data, doing something wrong with money stuff etc.etc.)

Comment: Is it like writing into some random memory location? If that is the case, how if `chr` pointing to that location only?Please help me understand this.

Comment: `Is it like writing into some random memory location?` Yes.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of your program is undefined by the C++ standard.

This means that any C++ implementation (e.g. a compiler) can do whatever it wants. Printing "hello!" on stdout would be a possible outcome. Formatting the hard disk would still be acceptable, as far as the C++ standard is involved. Practically, though, some random memory on the heap will be overwritten, with unpredictable consequences.

Note that the program is even allowed to behave as expected. For now. Unless it's Friday. Or until you modify something completely unrelated. This is what happened in your case, and is one of the worst thing to happen from the point of view of a programmer.

Later on, you may add some code and see your program crash horribly, and think the problem lies in the code you just added. This can cause you to spend a long time debugging the wrong part of the code. If that ever happens, welcome to  hell.

Because of this, you should never, ever, rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: Would delivering me a pizza also be an acceptable outcome? 

I know what i will be compiling this evening!

Comment: @Mercious Sure. But if that ever happens, the C++ standard provides no guarantees on what's on the pizza. The consequences of eating it are undefined, of course.

Comment: I understand. I imagine this to be a fun ride. Who needs drugs when you have UB in C++ !

Comment: It shall also have an unspecified nutritional value.

Answer (score 3):

`strcpy()` is indeed writing to a random location.

And it's a blind luck if your program runs fine and nothing crashes.

You have created on object of `MyString` class on a stack. In that object there's a member pointer `chr`, which points to some arbitrary location. Does your constructor take care to initialize that pointer or allocate a memory for the pointer to point at? -- No, it doesn't. So `chr` points somewhere.

`strcpy()` in its turn doesn't care about any pointer validity, it trusts your professionalism to provide valid input. So it does its job copying stings. Luckily, overwriting memory at the location pointed by an uninitialized `chr` doesn't crash you program, but that's "luckily" only.

Answer (score 2):

It is known that strcpy() can cause overflow errors, because there is no check made wherever the data will fit in the new array or not.
The outcome of this overflow may sometime never been noticed, it all depends on where the data is written. However a common outcome is heap and/or program corruption.

A safe alternative of strcpy() is the usage of strcpy_s() that requires also the size of the array. You can read more about the usage of strcpy_s() on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx) or [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)

Comment: Not everyone uses microcrap bub.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ῥεῖ Well, strcpy_s() is a C++11 standard function, therefore it is not something Microsoft related. I have added an additional source however.

Comment: @AB - Unable to confirm - where did find this idea of being standard function?  Neither cppreference.com nor cplusplus.com have it.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy has strcpy_s (its _C_ 11 though)

Comment: It was introduced in C++ 11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011), please have a look at my second link for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `strcpy()` does something like this:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
  unsigned i;
  for (i=0; src[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    dest[i] = src[i];
  dest[i] = '\0';
  return dest;
}
```

So, when you pass a pointer to some character array to `strcpy`, it copies data from `src` to `dest` until it reaches `NULL` terminated character.
Character pointer does not contain any information about length of string, so when you pass `dest` pointer, it copies data even though you haven't assigned memory to it.

Run this example code, you will get my point:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str1[] = "Hello_World!";
    char str2[5];
    char str3[10];
    strcpy(str2,str1);
    cout << "string 1:" << str1 << endl;
    cout << "string 2:" << str2 << endl;
    cout << "string 3:" << str3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This will not show any error but you can understand by my example that this is not a good practice.